# Remove SQL results that have associated "time_worked" records

Tags: mysql, sql

Edit: I have added at the bottom a clearer example of what I mean.

Here is the query, schema and results (can view on SQLfiddle if needed):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c36aa/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `effective_sn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial_num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_data` text,
  `trans_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_prev` text,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `effective_sn` (`effective_sn`),
  KEY `serial_num` (`serial_num`),
  KEY `type_index` (`type`),
  KEY `trans_date_index` (`trans_date`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1093579 ;

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `effective_sn`, `serial_num`, `actor`, `type`, `trans_data`, `trans_date`, `trans_prev`, `content`) VALUES
(1091622, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1435864188, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1091749, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1435926407, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092012, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436189497, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092085, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436199139, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092162, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436205996, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092240, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436211675, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092252, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436213410, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092288, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436217645, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1092376, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436277006, NULL, 'some comment'),
(1093530, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'time_worked', '60', 1436551662, NULL, NULL),
(1093531, 100628, 100628, 'jhvisser', 'comment', '', 1436551662, NULL, 'some comment');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *  FROM `transactions` WHERE `serial_num` = 100628 and (type='comment' or type='time_worked')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c36aa/1/0)**:

```
|      id | effective_sn | serial_num |    actor |        type | trans_data | trans_date | trans_prev |      content |
|---------|--------------|------------|----------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|--------------|
| 1091622 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1435864188 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1091749 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1435926407 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092012 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436189497 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092085 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436199139 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092162 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436205996 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092240 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436211675 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092252 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436213410 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092288 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436217645 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1092376 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436277006 |     (null) | some comment |
| 1093530 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser | time_worked |         60 | 1436551662 |     (null) |       (null) |
| 1093531 |       100628 |     100628 | jhvisser |     comment |            | 1436551662 |     (null) | some comment |
```

In this query I am showing the `time_worked` type just so you can see what I am referring to. I don't want `comment`s appearing in the results if there is a `time_worked` type record that was also created within 5 minutes before or after the time the comment record was created.

This may be confusing, but the idea itself is simple so I'll explain it with an example case. I am working with a time tracking application. A lot of times people make comments on the items and forget to log time worked. The idea is I want to find comments where time was not logged. People could realize they forgot and add the time worked a few minutes later, that is why I say it can be created 5 minutes before or after.

Looking at the results in the image above there would be 2 results that should not be there, and those are the last two as the time was added when the comment was made.

Is it possible to do something like this in SQL?

Edit:

Input: An SQL query like the one above. 
Output: I want to modify the existing query I have to get rid of "comment" types that have an associated "time_worked" type. When I am referring to type, I am referring to the actual column `type`, which has the data `comment` or `time_worked` within it. Essentially if there is a `time_worked` type and a `comment` with the same `trans_date` (unix time) they should not appear in the results.

So in the example data I gave the last two rows would not be showing.

Comment: It is very hard to ready this picture.   but which comment don't you want to appear.  be specific this question is quite vague. also showing input data and expected results would help.

Comment: Maybe next time you could create a schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ that way is easy to see where is the problem and come with a solution.

Comment: @Hogan I tried to make it a little clearer with my question. The source image actually is larger, Stackoverflow just has resized it. I added a direct link to the source image.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza added an sqlfiddle.

Comment: Told you a fiddle help a lot, Glad you solve your issue.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza definitely helped. I just didn't think it would work as I had a lot of data, but I realized I could just provide what was needed for this and sanitize the sensitive data out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is looking for records where an associated record in the same table does not exist with a certain type. For this purpose, use a LEFT self JOIN:

```
SELECT comments.*, DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(comments.
            trans_date), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), 
    timeworked.id
FROM transactions AS comments
LEFT JOIN transactions AS timeworked ON comments.
    serial_num = timeworked.serial_num
    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(comments.trans_date) BETWEEN 
            DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeworked.
                    trans_date), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
        AND DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeworked.
                    trans_date), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
    AND timeworked.type = 'time_worked'
WHERE comments.type = 'comment'
    AND timeworked.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The date column is the `trans_date` one. However I am getting an error when running this that `FUNCTION database.dateadd does not exist`

Comment: what is the data type for trans_date?

Comment: You can kind of see if in the results picture, but it is a timestamp.

Comment: I fixed the field name and the function name (I had put the SQL Server spelling in)

Comment: Getting a syntax error around the date_add section. Looks at some docs is the date_add function being used correct here? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Comment: Wow, my syntax from SQL Server is way off!

Comment: I tried to alter the code: http://pastebin.com/mh5H3esr . It is now not giving an error but also not returning anything so I may have done it wrong.

Comment: Your paste bin failed because you wrote  timeworked.trans_date between. Should be comments.trans_date between

Comment: The code you edited in has timeworked.trans_date between just like the one I wrote has? I am confused if this is how it should be or if you made a mistake as you just said it should be comments.trans_date? Your syntax on the date_add is still off it was giving errors. Once I fixed it up so there were no errors I get no results again just like with my paste

Comment: That version looks like it works. I just modified the `SELECT *` to a `SELECT comments.*` so that I am only getting the one tables data. Works as I wanted :). Thanks!

Comment: Hey! We got there in the end. Do you understand how it works?

Comment: Hold on, sorry I checked the results and it looks like it is just removing the item with the `time_worked` type. I tested comparing the original query in my OP to the new one from you and one gives 11 results, and yours gives 10. It should give 9 though as it should remove the comment with the id of `109531` as the time is within that of the `time_worked` time.

Comment: Here is the result from yours: http://i.imgur.com/jZvYuGY.png . Notice how that last comment is still there. It shouldn't be. It has the same time as the `time_worked` one.

Comment: How odd. I keep making changes to my code, but I can't check it against your data.

Comment: I will provide you with an SQL fiddle. Give me a few minutes I need to sanitize some data.

Comment: Here is an SQL fiddle that contains the schema, data from this one id, and the query/results of the original query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c36aa/1 . Run your query on this and you'll see how only the `time_worked` type is gone from the results, yet the last comment there should be gone as well as it is within that 5 minute period. Here is fiddle using your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c36aa/4 . Notice that only the one row is missing, when there should be 2 missing.

Comment: SQL fiddle did the trick. I was using DATE_ADD on a timestamp. Doesn't work like that. Here's your 9 results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c36aa/35

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is possible to do in SQL, here is one way to do it that would always work (note -- there may be better ways to do it but this will always work).  Since you question is kinda vague I can't be specific but I expect you will be able to use this to get a good result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT base.*,
         CASE WHEN (criteria for exclusion is true) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
  FROM
  (
     -- this is where you select your base data from your original table
     SELECT * 
     FROM table
  ) AS base
) as filter
WHERE FLAG != 1
```

If you have a requirement that criteria needs to check for another row in original data then you join to base in the innermost select statement.